# Is there any possibility to execute Javascript function using automation anywhere?

Tags: javascript, rpa, automationanywhere

I am able to execute JavaScript function into a web page using automation anywhere. It was opening an new window in internet explorer and executing the js function. But what I really need is to execute JavaScript function in already opened web page. I don't need to open new window and executing js function. Is there any possibility to do the same. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you open to use Node JS?

Comment: Sorry automation anywhere will not support node JS.

Comment: Automation Anywhere JavaScript support, via the Script command, uses something called JScript (in V11). It's not as full blown as JavaScript, so things like regexes don't work as you would expect. A lot of the regular JavaScript commands don't work well. You would be better off looking at the VB Scripting options to achieve the same result. It's far more useful when integrating with Automation Anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Object Cloning you can select the object and trigger an action based off of it, the JavaScript reference should be in the HTML HRef line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By using object cloning we cannot set values to a "readonly" element but while using JavaScript we can disable readonly attribute and set values through backend. that is why I need javascript function.